# Deformation Motion Blur and Vector Pass not working in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, motion-blur

I'm experiencing an odd behavior with deformation blur in Cycles with an specific model of an elephant even in a new scene.

When rendering with Motion Blur enabled I've got this render with only blur in its hair strands:
[image]

Here you have a render without Motion Blur for comparison:
[image]

The weird thing here is that if I add a new object and deform it with an armature, I do have the motion blur. But that's not all: if I render without MB, **the geometry is missing from the Vector Pass!!!** Only the strands are visible:
[image]

I've checked if I have a full Vector Pass in the Internal engine and I do:
[image]

The object have Motion Blur and Deformation enabled... I would like to share the file but I cannot as it is a Turbosquid model although I can share any screenshot. But normals are right, it doesn't work without the modifiers either or if I erase everything an apply an armature from the ground...

Do I missing something?

Comment: I found a "solution". If I join the elefant to a new object (then removing the object in edit mode) and re-apply the modifiers everything works. But I then need to comb again all the particle systems. So there's a difference between this model and a new one which causes this.

Comment: If you upload a blend file that demonstrates the problem, someone will find it much easier to help you.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't share it. Finally I found the problem, will post it tomorrow I need to finish this job today!

Comment: @GregZaal I suppose that it took me more than one day to post my answer, hehehe. Sorry, too much work :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model has active Auto Smooth Normals. Disabling it fix the problem.

[image]

It was a purchased model and it appears that Blender activated Auto Smooth when importing the FBX model.